# Serialize content hub pages

Tags: content-hub

We are using `Content Hub 4.2`. We want to serialize pages in the content hub. Is there any specific command to achieve this?

Also, while trying to serialize entities getting an error as `The specified resources were not found.`

[image]

We are able to serialize entity definitions and option list using the following commands-

> ch-cli serialization pull ed

How can we resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just to clarify you are serializing entities from Content Hub.  If so you need to reference the entity definition:

```
 # Pulling all entities for an entity definition
ch-cli serialization pull entity --definition <entity definition name>
```

https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/developers/cloud-dev/integration-tools--serialization.html